# How to extend xml template in Odoo 12

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I am trying to extend `CalendarView` template in my custom module.

Here is my code:

```
      <templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">

        <t t-name="CalendarView" t-extend="CalendarView">
          <t t-jquery=".o_calendar_sidebar_container d-none d-md-block" t-operation="replace">
            <div class="o_calendar_sidebar_container d-none d-md-block">
            <i class="o_calendar_sidebar_toggler fa"/>
            <div class="o_calendar_sidebar">
                <div class="o_calendar_mini"/>
            </div>
            <i class="o_calendar_sidebar_toggler fa"/>
            <div class="o_calendar_sidebar">
                <div class="o_calendar_mini"/>
            </div>
            <i class="o_calendar_sidebar_toggler fa"/>
            <div class="o_calendar_sidebar">
                <div class="o_calendar_mini"/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="o_calendar_sidebar_container d-none d-md-block">
            <p>AM here</p>
          </div>
          </t>
        </t>
      </templates>
```

But nothing happened in calendar view.
Note: If i replace the operation value `replace` with `inside, getting an error like the operation` inside` is not valid.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

I replaced the `t-jquery` values as this
   `<t t-jquery=".o_calendar_sidebar_container" t-operation="replace">`